# How to evaluate Database benchmarks ? What to consider given a specific example?

Tags: nosql, benchmark, neo4j, graph, arangodb

I'm trying to figure out which database to use for a project which is supposed to implement a temporal property graph model and I am looking into some benchmarks for that. I found some papers which provided some insights and results and I also found this benchmark from TigerGraph:

https://www.tigergraph.com.cn/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/EN0302-GraphDatabase-Comparision-Benchmark-Report.pdf

Does anyone have any idea why ArangoDB is performing so poorly here ? Especially in comparison to Neo4j ?

Furthermore, any preferences regarding a NoSQL database which consistently needs to write data while answering mostly queries which result in large subtrees ?

EDIT: Also - if someone has links to other benchmarks i'd welcome that.

Comment: Use a relational database instead of something faddish.

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert at all but to me - beside not answering my question at all - this statement seems kind of ignorant. A lot of graph data is semi-structured and therefore tables only make sense in some cases where nested table joins can do not occur on a regular basis. Graph databases mostly rely on  key-value or document stores for a reason. So at least explain you point please.

Comment: _"why ArangoDB is performing so poorly here ?"_ -- could that be because the benchmark is conducted by their competitor, perhaps?

Comment: Yes very true but this seems kind of obvious that they would choose workloads where TigerGraph  performs best. But its not about the results of TigerGraph - I am wondering why ArangoDB is so much worse than Neo4j in this benchmark and what the architectural explanation for this could be.

Comment: @L.Rex Graph databases are really for graph and tree-like problems actually, which are different use cases than document and key-value stores. While bbaird's comment might sound ignorant at face value, it's really not in actuality, since most *speciality* databases are just subsets of the relational database. Relational databases have been around long enough at this point that they've matured to cover 98% of problems in the world. The other 2% of problems are edge case use cases which is where a speciality database system *may* accel at. Also there's drawbacks in not using a mainstream system.

Comment: But graph databases often rely on key-value/document stores under the hood so you cannot separate them in general which makes a general assumption about statement about graph databases ridiculous. Which bbaird actually did not do - there are even graph databases which rely on a relational database but due to his detailedness I don't know what his point is here. Anyways it is still not the answer to my question. I will use a NoSQL database there is no way around it, so I am investigating them. The data I use IS perfectly made for a graph structure where temporal relations are  most critical.

Comment: Just hoped someone with experience and knowledge on NoSQL databases would drop by and have a simple explanation for this.

Comment: Oh, we have experience with NoSQL - there's a reason we continue to use relational databases, namely data integrity, speed, and ease of use/support.  Relational databases have supported graph structures logically from day 1 and natively within the database since recursion was added to the SQL standard.  When you say " I will use a NoSQL database there is no way around it" that tells me you're not familiar enough with the relational model to make that determination.  Create a question with what you're trying to achieve and I'll be happy to assist - just tag me in a comment when you're ready.

Comment: One of the major motivations behind the relational model that IBM was trying to solve was the Bill of Materials problem, which is a directed, acyclic graph.  The RM is built on top of a hierarchy of relations, itself a type of graph.  It's bad enough graph databases claim to do something relational databases can't, it's worse they completely ignore the functionality provided within the relational model.

Comment: "that tells me you're not familiar enough with the relational model to make that determination."

Comment: Nope. Just have to use a NoSQL Database because it's a given constraint in the research I am conducting. I have to implement a data model using a NoSQL database. Later research could include comparing the performance doing the exact same thing using a relational database system. As I said - I am no expert yet but from what I've read in research there are cases where NoSQL databases are faster regarding some types of query execution. Depending on what the main payload of queries looks like it should make sense sometimes. This does not reflect the actual state of production readiness of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just today, a new benchmark was released. For now, there are two graph databases in it, Neo4j and Memgraph. In the blog post, there is a link to GitHub repository and the methodology. I've read the comments from Memgraph team on Twitter and they say that they would like to include other systems into benchmark.

A blog post is located at https://memgraph.com/blog/memgraph-vs-neo4j-performance-benchmark-comparison.